# How to remove flickering from image?

Tags: photo-editing, image-processing, wedding

[image]

While taking photos at a wedding, I had flickering issues. One of the priests asked me to put my camera to silent mode and didn't notice that I'm taking photos with flickers then.

How can I fix the flickering?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - however, please note that we're not a traditional discussion forum but a dedicated Q&A site, so requests for services are off-topic here; I've removed that bit from your question, but hopefully the community will be able to help you with some techniques as to how to fix the images. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: "Who gives this woman… who gives… ***who gives this woman?!?***" "Uh, whut, sorry, on Facebook…"

Comment: For future reference on how to avoid a repeat: [What causes these inconsistent dark bands in some of my photos from an indoor event?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99456/15871)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing "banding" lines caused from using silent shutter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126642/removing-banding-lines-caused-from-using-silent-shutter)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different technique from the ones expounded in the answer linked on the comments. Using Gimp but PS should be able to do it too.

You are fortunate enough to have a plain wall in the background, so from that we can extract the actual flicker information, if we assume that the wall should be a uniform color to start with.

So:

- In the top left corner, sample the colors in the middle of a light band (around 144px down in you image) and the middle of the neighboring dark band (226px down) and assign them respectively to the Foreground and background colors.
- Create the following layer structure:

  - Your image at the bottom
  - Above it, a layer group that you put in Divide mode
  - In the layer group two layers, the top one being also in `Divide` mode
  - Bucket fill these two layers with the Foreground color (light band color)
- This should produce the initial image
  [image]
- Set the blend tool to:

  - Gradient: `Foreground to background (RGB)`
  - Shape: `Bi-linear`
  - Repeat: `Triangular wave`
- Create a vertical blend on the bottom layer in the group, starting from the middle of a light band, to the middle of the neighboring dark band. If you look at the whole image when doing this, the positions of the start and end of the blend are quite easy to determine because the image changes radically when you are close. The two places to look are:

  - The head of the person in focus
  - The top of the face mask of the person behind him (if the blend isn't correct the face mask will be overblown)
- You can further improve things by tweaking the gradient on the spot

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. I really appreciate it. However I never ever used GIMP before, so I really don't know where to start and learn how to do it. Is there any tutorial to watch? Can we connect through email?

Comment: Do you think this can be improved? like If I did it and really give time to edit. do you think there's still a chance to make it better?

Comment: The same technique can likely be used with PS. It can possibly be improved by using a gradient that better reproduces the flicker fall-off (sampling the gradient on the picture).

Comment: I am honestly not sure if the 'fixed' result looks much better than the starting point. You have managed to remove some of the low-frequency banding in the upper part of the background, but replaced it with a perhaps even more annoying higher frequency banding. In the lower part of the image, both in the background and over the jackets, the original low frequency banding is just as clearly visible as in the original image, perhaps even amplified.